# Visual Studio removes AXML layout every time I save it !!!! VS BUG?

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-layout, xamarin

Every time I change the layout (AXML file in the Layouts folder) Visual Studio removes it from the project without deleting it from disk, only removes it, and then I ave to add existing file and select the file.

No problems compiling and no problems anywhere only removes it when save. I think this is a BUG in Visual Studio because it don't have any sense. Tested on VS 2017 and 2019 Community.

Tested on VS 2017 and 2019. I add a AXML layout to Layouts folder in Xamarin project.. ok up to this point. Now I do some changes like add a button or something and when I save it Visual Studio removes the layout from the Layout folder but don't deletes it from disk.

Thanks

Comment: That doesn't quite make sense honestly, works perfectly for me. Might be something in your CSProj or Gitignore :/. Can you try it with a new Xamarin Solution? Does it still happen?

Comment: @AlejandroAlis,According to your description, you have one android project, then you add layout in Resources--layout folder, then you delete this layout file from project, you find it is still in Resource--layout folder, just don't display in project? I try it, but I don't have this issue, but please check the layout you added is xml or axml? And please share your visual studio version here.

Comment: Tested on VS 2017 and 2019. I add a AXML layout to Layouts folder in Xamarin project.. ok up to this point. Now I do some changes like add a button or something and when I save it Visual Studio removes the layout from the Layout folder but don't deletes it from disk.

Comment: I test it in VS 15.9.16 and VS 16.4.0, both of them are worked as normal.

Comment: I'm also seeing this behaviour with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.5.4 - very odd.

Comment: Happy to know that all the weird things don't just happen to my :)

Comment: Did you ever get the issue resolved @AlejandroAlis?

Comment: Hi @binncheol .. never, some month ago without working on this but I think the problem persist

Comment: Initially I found that ensuring any references to other views should use @+id/xxx not @id/xxx (as mentioned [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/361071/#Comment_361071)) which fixed the problem, but now I'm back looking at the same layout again (which still has all the correct id references) and VS2019 (updated to 16.10.2) is doing it's old trick of unloading the file for the project again...